# Inject application services instance in Angular 2

Tags: typescript, angular

I would like to have application-wide service.
In my app component, I defined

```
import {ItemService} from 'services/itemService';
import {ApplicationService} from 'services/applicationService';

@Component({
    selector: 'app',
    viewInjector: [ItemService, ApplicationService]
})
//...
```

And in my child views:

```
import {ItemService} from 'services/itemService';
import {ApplicationService} from 'services/applicationService';
//...
class MyView {
    constructor(itemService: ItemService, applicationSrevice:ApplicationService) {
    }
}
```

The problem is that every view create its services instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure it is the cleanest way to do it, but you have two options that will guarantee you have the same instance of the service all along.

The first way would be that instead of injecting the service in the child elements, you simply bind it through the properties, this would lead to the following Child :

```
import {ItemService} from 'services/itemService';
import {ApplicationService} from 'services/applicationService';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-view',
    properties: ['itemService : item-service', 'applicationService : application-service']
})
class MyView {
    private itemService : ItemService;
    private applicationService : ApplicationService
    constructor() {
    }
}
```

And you can use it with the following in the template of your parent :

```
<my-view [item-service]="itemService" [application-service]="applicationService"></my-view>
```

That is, if the constructor of your application component using itemService and applicationService as members of the component.

Another way to do it would be to use singleton, even though it is not very clean it will work and it will be available to any component easily.

Finally, depending on your needs, another cleaner way to do it would be to only inject your service in the component that should logically have it, and then this component would bind data coming from the service to the children with the same syntax I put above. If the children need to trigger a service call they can emit an event that the parent can listen to.

I hope I answered the question, if not, try to describe a little what is the goal.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of binding through properties.